# How to use getopt while get protected against code injection?

Tags: shell, security, eval, code-injection, getopt

[`getopt`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/getopt.1) is a very powerful program to parse command line arguments. As advised in its [EXAMPLE](https://man.archlinux.org/man/getopt.1.en#EXAMPLES) document, which is stored in my machine at `/usr/share/doc/util-linux-2.37.4/getopt.txt.bz2`, `eval set -- "$..."` is used to process the string output from `getopt`. `echo` sets the output back into the positional parameters. I understand the use of `eval` is important, or otherwise parameter with spaces will be split unintentionally.

```
PARSED=$(getopt -o 'abc:' --longoptions 'aaa,bbb,ccc:' -- "$@")

# Note the quotes around '$PARSED': they are essential!
eval set -- "$PARSED"
```

**`eval` seems to be essential by illustration of different cases:**

```
no_eval_no_quotes() {
    printf "\n${FUNCNAME[0]}\n"
    PARSED=$(getopt -o 'abc::' --longoptions 'aaa,bbb,ccc::' -- "$@")
    set -- $PARSED
    printf '[%s] ' "$@" ; printf '\n'
}

no_eval_with_quotes() {
    printf "\n${FUNCNAME[0]}\n"
    PARSED=$(getopt -o 'abc::' --longoptions 'aaa,bbb,ccc::' -- "$@")
    set -- "$PARSED"
    printf '[%s] ' "$@" ; printf '\n'
}

use_eval_no_quotes() {
    printf "\n${FUNCNAME[0]}\n"
    PARSED=$(getopt -o 'abc::' --longoptions 'aaa,bbb,ccc::' -- "$@")
    eval set -- $PARSED
    printf '[%s] ' "$@" ; printf '\n'
}

use_eval_with_quotes() {
    printf "\n${FUNCNAME[0]}\n"
    PARSED=$(getopt -o 'abc::' --longoptions 'aaa,bbb,ccc::' -- "$@")
    eval set -- "$PARSED"
    printf '[%s] ' "$@" ; printf '\n'
}

no_eval_no_quotes    -a -b 'with space' -c
no_eval_with_quotes  -a -b 'with space' -c
use_eval_no_quotes   -a -b 'with space' -c
use_eval_with_quotes -a -b 'with space' -c
```

**Analyse the outputs**

```
no_eval_no_quotes
[-a] [-b] [-c] [''] [--] ['with] [space']
```

Output of a shell script program (or function) can only be a string (by printf or echo), in addition to its numeric exit status. It cannot return an array. So `getopt` actually outputs a string of  `-a -b -c '' -- 'with space'`. **When there are no quotes, ALL the spaces are split.** Shell script does not understand any inner quotes, e.g. `'with space'`, within the string. (This is the main headache when I write shell scripts.)

```
no_eval_with_quotes
[ -a -b -c '' -- 'with space']
```

**If we put double quotes around a variable expansion, spaces are preserved.** Thus a string is not split by its spaces. Please note that this is not an array. If we put double quotes around an array expansion, it does split into its number of elements, while not splitting the spaces in each element (output as if the examples below).

```
use_eval_no_quotes
[-a] [-b] [-c] [] [--] [with space]
```

While `eval` is in use, it actually lets the shell to execute the command `set --  -a -b -c '' -- 'with space'`. So all arguments are correctly parsed.

```
use_eval_with_quotes
[-a] [-b] [-c] [] [--] [with space]
```

In this case, it does not matter if we put double quotes around the variable or not, because there is no globbing in the variable.

**Cons of using `eval`**

As we know the evil `eval` is subject to code injection vulnerability. When we expect plain text, evil code could be included in the input. It is because `eval` will execute the commands as if they are run in shell, it opens a big vulnerability.

```
code_injection() {
    eval $1
}

code_injection 'date; whoami; ls'
```

**Pros of using `eval`**

In the case of building the command line arguments, use of `eval` makes the code simpler, or otherwise we have to use non-POSIX standard arrays<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086#exceptions)</sup>, or passing arguments one-by-one separately.

**Thoughts of using `eval` or not**

As suggested by the `getopt` example, it uses `eval`. It seems that there are no other correct ways to parse the `getopt` output without using `eval`.

I believe most of the Linux programs use `getopt`, while [`getopts`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/getopts.1p.en) cannot parse long options. It means that, among most of the Linux programs, either their arguments with spaces will not be parsed correctly, or they use `eval`. Sanitizing `eval` input is difficult or otherwise impossible. **This makes most of the Linux programs are vulnerable to code injection.**

I did have a thought that *if one could execute a command on your system, you have bigger problem than code injection. Attacker can simply execute `rm -rf /`.* However it is not exactly the case. A system could take text parameters from an attacker, but not allowing him to run arbitrary commands directly on the console.

For a program X with [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) flag on, a restricted user, who is granted to run program X, can gain higher privilege by calling program X, is able to call higher privileged programs by code injection.

Is it true that most of the Linux programs use `getopt`? Are most of the Linux programs vulnerable to code injection?

While writing our shell scripts, how to use `getopt` while get protected against code injection? Or should we get rid of `getopt` and parse the arguments by ourselves?

Comment: What's the code injection vulnerability? Are you concerned about having to trust that `getopt`'s output is eval-safe? I don't think malicious user input can cause code injection since `getopt` does quote/escape everything correctly. `eval` is usually a red flag, although it *can* be used safely. `eval set -- "$(getopt ...)"` is one of the rare occasions I use it.

Comment: Scripts cannot be setuid, by the way. Only compiled binaries can be setuid.

Comment: "When it comes to eval, it does not matter if we put double quotes around the variable or not." It does insofar as quoting also inhibits globbing. An unquoted variable is liable to have its `*`, `?`, and other glob metacharacters expanded. Also, more esoterically, word splitting could produce unexpected results if `$IFS` contains non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Should I turn these comments into an answer? I want to make sure I've understood your question correctly before I post one. It would say, more or less, that the recommended `eval set` idiom is safe. But I might be missing something important.

Comment: To summarize John's comments: "How to use getopt while get protected against code injection?" Use it as documented, keeping all the variables quoted at all times.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - Thanks for pointing out my fault on double quotes. Obviously `getopt` does not sanitise inputs, thus its output won't be eval-safe. I think running `getopt` in a sub-shell cannot avoid the `rm -rf /` to be injected.

Comment: It doesn't sanitize, it escapes, which is even better than sanitizing. As far as I know it always produces safe, properly escaped output. I would love to see a counterexample if you know of one.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - I think I might be worrying too much. It seems that as the $PARSED variable is after `--`, code injection are treated as literal text. `code_injection() { PARSED=$(getopt -o 'abc::' --longoptions 'aaa,bbb,ccc::' -- "$@"); eval set -- "$PARSED"; printf '[%s] ' "$@"; }; code_injection -a -b 'with space; date' -c='with space; "date'`

Comment: @midnite,  That example does not demonstrate code injection.